# Retrive data according to App Language on Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, internationalization

I've implemented the internalization into my Flutter app.

I will have to document database on firebase according to two different languages. I would like to show the document according to app language. I mean if an English user is request a data from the database app will retrieve the data from English database. For the other language it will retrieve the data from second language database.

How can I handle it?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this article about `Internationalizing a full stack ios app firebase` [part 1](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/internationalizing-a-full-stack-ios-app-firebase-part-1-user-interface/) and [part 2](https://phrase.com/blog/posts/internationalizing-a-full-stack-ios-app-firebase-part-2-firebase-i18n/). In the part 2, in the section `Internationalizing our iOS App with Firebase: Localizing the Firestore Collection` you can find an example of the Firestore model (of course,according to their solution) but it is an approach about how you can model it:

```
product-feed-i18n
└── locales
    ├── ar
    |   ├── 0qKcByHYIc7Wi7XZSIzH
    |   |   ├── discount: "تخفيض ٢٠٪"
    |   |   ├── name: "نايك اير"
    |   |   └── ...
    |   └── 57bEpulnmwUGhI2oRJAV
    |       └── ...
    └── en
        ├── e8xUGV743gcGfOUKJvx4
        |   ├── discount: "20% off"
        |   ├── name: "Nike Air"
        |   └── ...
        └── rOExjrtGXXiaK0DsRCqD
            └── ...
```

There explains that instead of their documents nesting directly in the product-feed collection (which was the original before internalizing process), their new product-feed-i18n collection has them broken up per-locale. They have an empty locales document that allows them to add a collection for each locale under it. Their documents are then placed in each of these collections with their translations.

I found the articles interesting, I think they can be hepful.

Comment: Thank you! I will check all of the documents 